# Transposing data

Tags: r, duplicates

What I am trying to do is to go from a data configuration like this

```
SAMPLE  ENTRY          Rep2
4707890 23.323366       1
4707890 23.320814       2
4712037 33.1122         1
4712037 33.1122         2
4719912 3.01136         1
4719912 3.0305          2
4719912 3.01136         3
4714257 81.5364         1
4714257 86.20892366     2
```

to one like this

```
SAMPLE  ENTRY          Rep2 1               2               3
4707890 23.323366       1   23.323366       23.320814   
4707890 23.320814       2           
4712037 33.1122         1   33.1122         33.1122 
4712037 33.1122         2           
4719912 3.01136         1   3.01136         3.0305          3.01136
4719912 3.0305          2           
4719912 3.01136         3           
4714257 81.5364         1   81.5364         86.20892366 
4714257 86.20892366     2
```

In essence, samples with replicate results, identified in the table by having the same sample number and sequential replicate numbers, have their Entry values transposed into columns associated with the first replicate. The replicate number can vary but I have never seen it more than 12.

I suspect it can be done with a melt/cast type of process but have had no joy so far.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alexis_laz:  I have found a variant of what you put up gets me there:

DF2 <- merge(DF, dcast(DF, value.var = "ENTRY", SAMPLE ~ Rep2)).
DF2[DF2$Rep2 > 1, -(1:3)] <- NA

For some reason 'reshape' was giving me grief when applied to the multicolumn df I am trying to bend to my will.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this looks valid, at least with the sample data:

```
DF2 = merge(DF, reshape(DF, direction = "wide", idvar = "SAMPLE", timevar = "Rep2"))
DF2[DF2$Rep2 > 1, -(1:3)] <- NA
DF2
#   SAMPLE    ENTRY Rep2  ENTRY.1  ENTRY.2 ENTRY.3
#1 4707890 23.32337    1 23.32337 23.32081      NA
#2 4707890 23.32081    2       NA       NA      NA
#3 4712037 33.11220    1 33.11220 33.11220      NA
#4 4712037 33.11220    2       NA       NA      NA
#5 4714257 81.53640    1 81.53640 86.20892      NA
#6 4714257 86.20892    2       NA       NA      NA
#7 4719912  3.01136    1  3.01136  3.03050 3.01136
#8 4719912  3.03050    2       NA       NA      NA
#9 4719912  3.01136    3       NA       NA      NA
```

Comment: +1! about to put the same thing ! maybe you can add an order step to get the desired OP output! `DT[order(DT$SAMPLE,DT$ENTRY,DT$Rep2),]`

Comment: @agstudy : I'm not sure how to use `order` this way, correctly, to match the exact output. I could only come up with `DF2[order(match(DF2$SAMPLE, unique(DF$SAMPLE))), ]`. Feel free to edit, obviously!

Comment: Thank you.  It definitely does what I want on the dummy data but I need to get my head around how to apply it to a different data set.  Giving errors with that at the moment but gives me hope.  Thanks once again.

Comment: @Lee_Kennedy : You 're welcome! Perhaps, you could edit your question with sample data that reproduce the errors you get? Or, maybe, the `str` or `dput` of the actual data will be helpful.

Comment: @alexis_laz - I am wanting to transpose the ENTRY values based on Rep2 and SAMPLE_NUMBER.  Ooops - I'll edit and return - the str is too long.

Comment: 'data.frame': 822 obs. of  16 variables:
 $ SAMPLE_NUMBER : int  
 $ LOGIN_DATE    : chr  "
 $ CUSTOMER      : chr  "
 $ PRODUCT       : chr  "
 $ PRODUCT_GRADE : chr  "
 $ X_CLIENT_CODE : chr  ""
 $ ANALYSIS      : chr  
 $ REPORTED_NAME : chr  " 
 $ REPORTED_UNITS: chr  "
 $ ENTRY         : num  
 $ DATE_STARTED  : chr  
 $ group2        : Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 
 $ RD            : chr  "D" "R" "D" "R" ...
 $ Rep2          : int  1 2 1 2 1 2 3 4 1 2 ...
 $ Type          : chr  
 $ STATUS        : chr  "

Comment: I have found a variant of what you put up gets me half way there: DF2 <- merge(DF, dcast(DF, value.var = "ENTRY", SAMPLE_NUMBER ~ Rep2)).  I couldn't get reshape to work but managed dcast.   But it replicates all results against all Rep2 values.  How to I trim it back to being transposed just against item 1?

Comment: By George, (and Alexis) I think I've done it!  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Lee_Kennedy : I 'm not sure I got it right, but the problem was on how to remove the elements from `Rep2 > 1`? In any case, glad I could be of help! (PS: Also, you could edit mine or add (and accept) your own solution.)